# Javascript execute two functions onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of 5 functions that return either `true` or `false` and another function `showResults` that should **only** run if all 5 functions return `true`. How do I add this to the `onclick` property of a **HTML button**. Here's my code:

```
<input type="button"  value="Search" onclick="return (validateTitle() & validateYear() & validatePrice() & validateComment() & validateFormat());showResults();" />
```

Comment: you better execute 1 function which will execute the 5 firsts functions and then execute the 6th if everything before returned true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try providing a handler function to the onclick event.

```
function handleClick() {
 if(validateTitle() && validatePrice() && validateComment() &&validateFormat()) {
  showResults();
 }
}
```

In HTML

```
<input type="button"  value="Search" onclick="handleClick();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#" onclick="calculate()">`Click here to call multiple functions

```
function calculate() {
    var a = add();
    var b = substract();
    var c = division();
    var d = result();
    if( a && b && c && d ){
     return showResult();     
    }
}
```